# Redirect to external landing page from SF microsite

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I was wondering if it's possible to redirect customers to an external landing page after clicking on a submit button? so for example after opting in via clicking on a submit button redirect them to www.google.com

Comment: @NITHESHK This question is related to salesforce marketing cloud not Salesforce CRM

Comment: @PraveenKumarBandi Sorry My bad,Not read properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect function for that %%=Redirect('http://example.com')=%%, see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirect.htm

I'd use this function on the target landing page that is opened after clicking on the submit button.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to auto-redirect after 20 seconds. as I understand this redirect you need to click on a link to redirect you to an external page?

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to redirect after someone clicked on the submit button. If so, you'll need a landing page, where this submit leads you to. If you place the redirect function on this landing page, it'll redirect without any need to click another link. 
If you want to redirect with a 20 seconds delay you might want to use meta refresh in you HTML, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh